# I do not hide dropdown clicking outside the element

Tags: jquery, html, liferay-6

I'm doing a drop-down button to Liferay.

The functionality of the Bootstrap own 2 Liferay not work for me, then I created one of 0.

I open one or the other depends on which button is elected. And my hide if I calc over the item.

But I fault when you click anywhere outside of the html I just hide the drop-down.

That is failing me?

HTML

```
<div id="desplegableBoton">
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Configurar <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Cambio de canal Wifi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recuperación de contraseña wifi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Velocímetro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contratar upgrade</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Consultar <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Cambio de canal Wifi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recuperación de contraseña wifi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Velocímetro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contratar upgrade</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    </div>      
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
desplegable: function() {
        $('.btn').unbind().click(function(){
            $('.btn.active').next('.dropdown-menu').slideUp();
            $('.btn.active').removeClass('active');
             $(this).stop().toggleClass('active');
             $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideToggle();   
             $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                    if (!$('.btn.active').is(e.target) && $('.btn.active').has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.active').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                                        $('.btn.active').removeClass('active');
                        console.log("aaa");
                    }
                });
         });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `blur()` to detect when something else has been clicked.

`blur()` is a function that is called when an element "loses focus", which means that if you click outside of an item that you were interacting with, `blur()` is called

This might help you:

```
$('#desplegableBoton').blur(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp();
});
```